# Limit GET/POST not working in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

i have some files as shown below

```
  |.htaccess
  |-index.php
  |-subfolder
       |--.htaccess
```

one `.htaccess` file is in root folder,another `.htaccess` file is in one subfolder

The root's `.htaccess` have this below code

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'abc.web.com'">
php_value auto_prepend_file "/var/www/vhosts/abc.web.com/common.php"
</If>
<Else>
php_value auto_prepend_file "/var/www/vhosts/def.web.com/common.php"    
</Else>
```

and subfolder's `.htaccess` file having the below code

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/abc.web.com/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthType Basic
<Limit GET>
 require valid-user
</Limit>
```

Now the problem is `<Limit GET>` block is working only after commenting out the `If else` block in the root's `.htaccess` file.

if the `if else` code block is present in the root's .htaccess file then the `Limit get` code block in the subfolder's .htaccess file is not working.

Any idea why its behaving like this !

**Edit - 1:**

Even if i comment out the code in `If` and `Else` blocks of root's `.htaccess` file still the `Limit` thing is not working in subfolder's `.htaccess`

> Root's `.htaccess`

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'abc.web.com'">
#php_value auto_prepend_file "/var/www/vhosts/abc.web.com/common.php"
</If>
<Else>
#php_value auto_prepend_file "/var/www/vhosts/def.web.com/common.php"    
</Else>
```

The `Limit` in sub folder's `htaccess` only working if i completely comment out/remove the total `If` `Else` blocks of root `.htaccess` !!

Why is this dependency between both `.htaccess` files !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is resolved by adding the below rewrite in subfolder's `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

no idea why this rule was needed

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your `%{HTTP_HOST}` value is `'www.abc.web.com'` and not just `'abc.web.com'`, and that's why the `if-else` matching is failing to work as you expect.

Comment: Seems more of a comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Although it doesn't provide a solution, this is an attempt to answer OP's bottom line: "*Any idea why its behaving like this!*"

Comment: @BeetleJuice Agreed. So, we're all assuming the OP should be marking this as the "solution" *lol!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can't tell if you're being sarcastic. I wasn't making the point that it's the best possible answer or even a good one; only that it can pass as an answer to the given OP statement.

Comment: @BeetleJuice well not really "sarcastic" per se. I just found this to be more of a glorified comment since the words *"One possibility"* falls into that I find. I just won't upvote it though, nor will I downvote. The OP will need to also be heard here and we don't know "where" they went, or it hasn't answered/solved their question and that they're looking for someone to solve it.

Comment: hey hi, thats for the response, but thats not the issue, i have updated my question `Edit-1`, once please check it, thank you